# We ain't lost, <tag question verb> we?

Tags: tag-questions, dialect

All,

Other than "*, are we*", what are the other possible tag question verb forms below?

> We ain't lost, [tag question verb] We?

What if the sentence was:

> We ain't seen anything like this before, [tag question verb] we?

Note: cross posted

***Edit:*** cross posted as I ain't lost, am I! I forgot to edit that pronoun.

Comment: I don't see how *am I?* fits either sentence as an optional tag question.

Comment: @AlanCarmack Thanks for the note. You could check the post to  know why.

Comment: If you admit *ain't*, then whether *are* or *is* appears in the tag is going to be a minor concern. There are people in Appalachia or the South who might say *we is* — hence Cynthia Shearer, *We ain't lost; we is exploring* — and I might expect those people to say *is we?* in turn.

Answer (score 2):

For the first question, the answer depends on whether *lost* is a verb or an adjective. *Ain't* can either be short for *have not* or *are not*, and for this question, both possibilities work.

If your team is down 8-3 in the last inning of a baseball game, the right tag is

> We ain't lost, have we?

If you are in the middle of some dense woods and have no idea which way to go to get out, the right tag is

> We ain't lost, are we?

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'are' for the first sentence:

> "We ain't lost, [are] we?"

and 'have' for the second one:

> We ain't seen anything like this before, [have] we?

Comment: Welcome to English Language Learners! Please [edit] to include an explanation of *why* this is correct; answers without explanation do not teach the patterns of the language well.

Comment: Thanks Ksisky. There was a slip in my post. As for your answer, are there any other answers to my question? I'm still asking because I already know what you pointed out. It was a mistake on my part that I didn't proof-read the post.